# Spring-Security: How to implement Authentication using WebSocket-scoped bean

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

trying to solve [How to combine Spring Security and js sockjs-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662289), I want to implement authentication of websocket sessions running on non-authenticated https Sessions (because of sockjs-client limitation).

I am thinking along the lines of:

1. on CONNECT message, pass credentials. An interceptor checks the credentials, and sets the authentication principal in a WebSocket-scoped bean. [1]
2. during other requests, an interceptor checks the WebSocket-scoped bean, and sets the Authentication objects in the SecurityContext, so that ChannelSecurityInterceptor can retrieve it.

Currently I fail getting an interceptor to be called before springs ChannelSecurityInterceptor, and I am not sure WebSocket-scoped beans can be used to hold a principal.

Or should I rather use DefaultHandshakeHandler.determineUser() to set a principal based on information from the handshake request? Would that work with ChannelSecurityInterceptor?

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-websocket-scope